# Charge Stripe billing address erroring if it includes a hyphen

Tags: stripe, charge

I am getting a "Must be a valid string" error on the billing name field in a charge form if the name contains a hyphen.

Any idea where that is coming from? I can't track it down.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this as we have the same issue?

Comment: Nope, sorry. It kind of got put on the back burner because of other priorities but I will need to get it fixed at some point.

Comment: I got an email back from Charge, , preg_match("/[^\pL\d\s\-]/u", $val, $matches);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an email back from Charge, you need to edit That's just one change in mod.charge.php, changing the regex to :

```
preg_match("/[^\pL\d\s\-]/u", $val, $matches);
```

They are working on a fix for this at the moment.

Comment: Good info, thanks for posting it back here.